# how to access output from sum() before it changes

Tags: python, sum, timedelta

If I cook this at an interactive prompt it returns one format - one I want at the moment.

But if I assign it to a variable and then print or use the variable like in the second example (same as in my file) it's in a different format.

How do I access the first output -

Thank you very much for any help.

```
import datetime
tote = datetime.timedelta(0, 25200), datetime.timedelta(0, 25200)
sum(tote, datetime.timedelta(0))
datetime.timedelta(0, 50400)


import datetime
tote = datetime.timedelta(0, 25200), datetime.timedelta(0, 25200)
brac = sum(tote, datetime.timedelta(0))
print brac
14:00:00



import datetime
tote = datetime.timedelta(0, 25200), datetime.timedelta(0, 25200)
brac = sum(tote, datetime.timedelta(0))
print repr(brac)
datetime.timedelta(0, 50400)
datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(repr(brac))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'total_seconds' requires a 'datetime.timedelta' object but 
received a 'str'
```

Comment: I removed the semicolons; Python runs just fine without them if you put your statements on separate lines (and it is more readable too).

Comment: And it is not clear what you are asking. `brac` is equal to `datetime.timedelta(0, 50400)`, but the string representation for that object is `14:00:00`. Use `print repr(brac)` instead.

Comment: I think that's exactly what he's asking, Martijn, is how to use `repr()` to look at an object instead of its string representation

Comment: I KNOW and I'm sorry. I am still working on making stuff post here properly formatted. Sorry I wasn't shouting, you all posted while I was looking out the window.

Comment: Perfect, thanks to you both.

Comment: Dagnabit, I thought I would then be able to use it in the total_seconds /60/60 type of operation. But timedelta.total_seconds errors that it is still getting a string. How can I get the object that timedelta says it wants?

Comment: Never mind I put the sum() operation directly as an argument to total_seconds and it does what I want. Believe it or not I am reading all the tutorials and docs I can find. It's hard not to just jump in and have some fun least it be like work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python interactive shell echos the results of expressions using the `repr()` function, but `print` uses `str()` to convert values to a string.

In both cases `sum()` produces the *exact same result*, but in your first sample, you see the interpreter print the output with `repr()`, in your second result you used `print` and the result was converted to a string with `str()`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> tote = datetime.timedelta(0, 25200), datetime.timedelta(0, 25200)
>>> brac = sum(tote, datetime.timedelta(0))
>>> brac
datetime.timedelta(0, 50400)
>>> print brac
14:00:00
>>> repr(brac)
'datetime.timedelta(0, 50400)'
```

There is nothing else you need to do; you already have the same result assigned to `brac`.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `print brac`, you're accessing the object's string representation. What you probably want is `print repr(brac)`, which gives you the format as produced by your first code example.